# Why sticky sidebar not floating

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is a sample where I take the affix for the right sidebar (unfortunately, Bootstrap 4 hasn't true affixes) - [Violy Theme Right Sidebar Sample](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/violy-creative-studio-html-template/full_screen_preview/25244565?_ga=2.33317303.884744446.1599592338-577048642.1596530374)
I see that sticky behavior made by this style:

```css
.sidebar {
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 25px 25px;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

So, when I duplicate sticky behavior in CSS for my page [here](http://bulash.ru/user_agreement.html) - nothing happened, right sidebar scrolled with text :-(
What's wrong?

Guess, written text is not enough to provide a clear answer, so, please look into browser Developer Tools for these pages to inspect styles and elements.

Comment: Weird that they both have the same code but one is sticky and the other one is not. The only difference is that yours is a constructed stylesheet.

Comment: are you talking about the social media side bar on the right ? maybe if you could create a codepen or fiddle to play with I can help you yes

Comment: @LaurentC This is the link, I hope: https://violy.astroon.pro/right_sidebar_blog.html

Comment: @m4n0 Yes, exactly

Comment: The sticky property works on the menu. But not even on the container left to the sidebar.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code in a [MRE]. External links are fine as long as you *also* include the relevant code here. Otherwise once you fix the problem the details are no longer available and the question becomes invalid and not useful to other users in future.

Comment: @ValeryBulash the sticky positioning does not have full browser support right now and I avoid using it for that reason. See here: https://caniuse.com/css-sticky // My idea is that you could use fixed positioning with a top at approx.425px and add a few lines of code inn JS to change that to top:0 or top:25px once we scroll past the first screen/100vh. What do you tyhink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can happen for many reasons: Position sticky will most probably not work if overflow is set to hidden, scroll, or auto on any of the parents of the element.

In fact, in your [site](http://bulash.ru/user_agreement.html) I found that its parent element:

```
<header id="head_page">...</header>
<section class="wrapper>
<!--- here we find the sidebar -->
</section>
<footer id="footer>...<footer>
```

has a `overflow: hidden;` property and when I disabled it the property of `position: sticky;` started working again.

Comment: interesting, but I can't find the `overflow` property set to `hidden` for the parent element of `.sidebar` (which is `.wrap_sidebar`) ?

Comment: I'm talking about the main `<section class="wrapper>` between `header` and `footer`. I found it and disabled it. You can check.

Comment: OK I'll have a look now, that would indeed be a cleaner fix.

Comment: got it. and it doesnt seem to break anything else on the page, so good job, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Please see @despotes quick fix, that preserves the use of sticky positioning on the page.

I will leave my fixed positioning solution as a reference for future users.

Using fixed positioning that is more evenly supported:

**CSS**

```
.sidebar {
  position:fixed;
  top:425px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
      $(window).scroll(function() { 
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > XX) { //value to be determined
          $('.sidebar').css('top','25';
          }
        if ($(document).scrollTop() < XX) { // same value but add 1
          $('.sidebar').css('top','425';
        }
      });
      
});
```

So basically once the user scrolls past XX, the sidebar will sit 25px below the top of the screen and when under XX it will sit at 425px from the top. Could be edited with more trigger points for smoother effect.